# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.rpc.context'

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, pip, python-import

I'm getting this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.rpc.context'

when I import the Google Cloud Logging library for Python:

```
import google.cloud.logging
```

How to solve that, please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had some old packages installed, because the issue was solved by:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```